# can't access my web server from my public ip on a different network

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, web-hosting

I'm trying to set up webpage using nginx, i still have the default page just to test

everything is working fine when i try to get the page localy, whether i use the private or public ip or the domain name.

but once i try using a different network the browser says that the server is not connecting.
i made sure that my router is configured correctly and is forwarding right (i can ssh from my public ip just fine).

I'm on ubuntu 20.04
Using nginx

sorry if I'm missing something this is my first attempt at webhosting

Comment: Did you edit your DNS records with the domain registrar to point to the webserver?

Comment: yes, as i said when i visit the page whether I'm using the domain name or the public ip it works when on local network, whenever i switch to different network thats the problem